# Session Value is not correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 tables, User and RolesDetail 
and
I want to store Session["role"] from RolesDetail but when i stored the value is System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.....

I want to store session with value from joined table

```
public ActionResult Login(User u)
    {
        var user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Username == u.Username && a.Password == u.Password);

        if (this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha Is Not Valid !!"))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                Session["role"] = user.RolesDetail.Roles;
                Session["user"] = user.Username;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is Wrong !!");
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ErrMessage = "Error: Captcha Is Not Valid !!";
        return View();
    }
```

Session["user"] work just fine

Comment: `user.Username` is certainly a string and stored successfully, so I want to know what kind of data stored in `user.RolesDetail.Roles` before storing into session variable.

Comment: user.RolesDetail.Roles is string the values are like 'Administrator', 'Member', etc

Comment: Is the value stored in session become text of type names (`System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`...) instead of role names? And can you show model code to check what kind of `RolesDetail` consists of?

Comment: From interim code analysis, `SingleOrDefault` returns single `User` entity based from given criteria, then `user.RolesDetail.Roles` may return collection of multiple role names instead of one string like `user.Username` does, hence `user.RolesDetail.Roles` probably store `Roles` in session as type names instead of their values.

Comment: SOLVED: I just add ".ToString()". Thx anyway